Create CDS archive for Spring Cloud GCP project
I'm trying to create an CDS Archive for my Spring Cloud GCP project based on official documentation. However, it works well on demo and JDBC related projects. For Spring Cloud GCP one, a lot of Configurations depend on GCP Beans availability. All of them can be instantiated as NoOp of course but the goal is create real beans.
Maybe I did this feature wrongly and real beans are not required. If anyone, has a success in creating CDS Archive for Spring GCP project - please share.
